# Review Reopen Votes broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

The review queue [Reopen Votes](https://superuser.com/review/reopen) seems to be malfunctioning.

When I try review questions, it says *loading item* [image], but it never finishes.

After a while, the JavaScript Console shows

> Unexpected response code: 503

I've tried the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox (Ubuntu). The remaining review queues are not affected.

I'm not sure if this is a network wide issue. The few other sites where I have access to the Reopen Votes review queue don't have any pending questions.

Comment: Same symptom here.

Comment: seems borked on Server Fault (OS X / Safari 6.0.2) too. I think the back-end script needs a cookie

Comment: For me it works on [su] and is broken on [sf]

Comment: Hm, I spoke too soon. It broke on SU after I reviewed a couple of items. So it's definitely across multiple sites.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's fine to report network-wide bugs on per-site Metas. They don't need to be migrated to [metase].

Comment: Is this still happening? This may have been caused by network-wide timeouts we experienced earlier today.

Comment: @Emmett: The review queue on SU is empty now (sounds good) and I can access it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General network problems earlier today caused a lot of requests to 503, not just in review. Sorry about that – it should be fixed now.